can i fix buildozer erorr?
--------------------------- environments --------------------
ubuntu --> 20.04.6 LTS
buildozer --> 1.5.1.dev0
--------------------------- buildozer.spec --------------------

# This .spec config file tells Buildozer an app's requirements for being built.
#
# It largely follows the syntax of an .ini file.
# See the end of the file for more details and warnings about common mistakes.

[app]

title = kivy simple app
package.name = kivyallineone
package.domain = jp.rill.kivyallineone
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
version = 12.9
requirements = python3,kivy
orientation = portrait
osx.kivy_version = 2.1.0
osx.python_version = 3.8
fullscreen = 0
android.api = 35
android.minapi = 34

android.ndk_path = ./android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27

android.sdk_path = ./commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest

android.release_artifact = aab

p4a.branch = develop


ios.kivy_ios_url = h://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master


ios.ios_deploy_url = h://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.12.2


ios.codesign.allowed = false


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1




--------------------------- ERROR(config.log)    --------------------
ibffi/config.log
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libffi configure 3.4.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_34/libffi/configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_34/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = i-52100000580856
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.4.0-66-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
PATH: /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27
PATH: /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest/tools
PATH: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
PATH: /home/ubuntu/environments/my_env/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin
PATH: /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2703: checking build system type
configure:2717: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2737: checking host system type
configure:2750: result: aarch64-unknown-linux-android
configure:2770: checking target system type
configure:2783: result: aarch64-unknown-linux-android
configure:2880: checking for gsed
configure:2911: result: sed
configure:2939: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3007: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3018: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3073: result: yes
configure:3127: checking for aarch64-linux-android-strip
configure:3154: result: /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded      
configure:3219: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3258: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3265: checking for gawk
configure:3281: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3292: result: gawk
configure:3303: checking whether make -j1 sets $(MAKE)
configure:3325: result: yes
configure:3354: checking whether make -j1 supports nested variables
configure:3371: result: yes
configure:3516: checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc
configure:3543: result: /usr/bin/ccache /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC
configure:3812: checking for C compiler version
configure:3821: /usr/bin/ccache /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC --version >&5
Android (8490178, based on r450784d) clang version 14.0.6 (h://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android34
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
configure:3832: $? = 0
configure:3821: /usr/bin/ccache /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -v >&5
Android (8490178, based on r450784d) clang version 14.0.6 (h://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android34
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fomit-frame-pointer' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fPIC' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
configure:3832: $? = 0
configure:3821: /usr/bin/ccache /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3832: $? = 1
configure:3821: /usr/bin/ccache /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:3832: $? = 1
configure:3852: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3874: /usr/bin/ccache /home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -target aarch64-linux-android34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -DANDROID -I/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/android-ndk-r27-linux/android-ndk-r27/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/kivyallineone/arm64-v8a/include/python3.1   -L/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/kivyallineone/arm64-v8a conftest.c  >&5
ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3878: $? = 1
configure:3916: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libffi"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libffi"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libffi 3.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "h://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libffi"
| #define VERSION "3.4.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3921: error: in `/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_34/libffi':
configure:3923: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

i tyied many times with many information but always show same error...
please help me.
i have to update android api to "over34" as soon as possible.
